# Exception in listener attached to multiple buttons in barcode app

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing

Okay, So I am developing an in house barcode scanner for my company to use when we move computers and equipment. I am currently almost through setting up the Zxing Barcode Scanner Via Intent after some trial and error.

Here is what I'm trying to do.

Next to three `EditText` fields I have Three `ImageButtons` that when clicked, implement the `BarcodeScanner`, once scanned returns the value and inputs the value into the `EditText` field. I was able to do it successfully using one "listener" corresponding to one `ImageButton`. But after trying to use multiple `Buttons` with one listener, it calls the barcode scanner but crashes when trying to return the barcode value.

The Debugger shows the main Thread Suspended and I have to resume the debugger twice before the `RuntimeException` error appears in Logcat.

here's the error log from LogCat:

> 07-17 17:38:49.251: E/AndroidRuntime(30942):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.fmi.inventory/com.fmi.inventory.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=49374, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }}
>   to activity {com.fmi.inventory/com.fmi.inventory.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Here is my MainActivity:

```
package com.fmi.inventory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton button;
    ImageButton button1;
    ImageButton button2;
    EditText editField;
    Activity activity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        activity = this;
        button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.scanCubeID);
        button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.scanEmployeeID);
        button2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.scanConfigID);
        button.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button2.setOnClickListener(listener);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    public void setCubeClick(){
        editField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCubeID);
    }

    public void setEmployeeClick(){
        editField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmployeeID);
    }

    public void setConfigClick(){
        editField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editConfigID);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.initiateScan();

        }
    };

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                IntentResult intentResult = IntentIntegrator
                        .parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

                if (intentResult != null) {

                    String contents = intentResult.getContents();
                    String format = intentResult.getFormatName();
                    this.editField.setText(contents);
                    // this.elemQuery.setText(contents);
                    //this.resume = false;
                    Log.d("SEARCH_EAN", "OK, EAN: " + contents + ", FORMAT: "
                            + format);
                } else {
                    Log.e("SEARCH_EAN", "IntentResult je NULL!");
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.e("SEARCH_EAN", "CANCEL");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my layout .xml for MainActivity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editCubeID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/scanEmployeeID"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/scanCubeID"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_cubeid" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editEmployeeID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/scanConfigID"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editCubeID"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editCubeID"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_employeeid" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editConfigID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/scanConfigID"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editEmployeeID"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editEmployeeID"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_configid" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/scanCubeID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_scan"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/scanEmployeeID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scanCubeID"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_scan"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/scanConfigID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scanEmployeeID"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_scan"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editConfigID"
        android:text="@string/button_continue" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: always add full logcat in question,,,its key to unlock a lock...

Comment: From the LogCat, I can tell you're running into a `NullPointerException`. Place breakpoints and step through your code to see what's null.

Comment: Please change the subject of your question to something that better conveys the problem you are having.

Comment: @Samir Mangrolia - OKay I will remember.

Comment: @Yawus Yeah, I'm trying that just gotta get used to the Debugger. My professors have been ,aking us use jGrasp instead of Eclipse.

Comment: @prolink007 Sorry prolink! I was having issues with the question posting and i assumed it wasn't going through!

Comment: @DylanPage: No problem, just wanted you to be able to get people to look at your question. With the other subject, people would be less likely to click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `Activity` come in `onActivityResult` after scanning.You are accessing `editField` but it is **NULL**.

as you never Initialized it..

You are Initializing them in `setCubeClick`, `setEmployeeClick` or `setConfigClick`,

But I am  affraid they never called..Try to `Initialize` them in `OnCreat`